# Makefile for compiling files under different directories

Tags: compilation, makefile

---

```
                                   projectroot/
                                         |
          +------------------------------+----------------------------+
          |                              |                            |
       include/                        libs/                     helloworld/
          |                              |                            |
     shader_utils.h                shader_utils.c                 triangle.c
```

---

there are three directories under project root directory. helloworld directory contains triangle.c which depends on shader_utils.h(under projectroot/include) whose definition is under projectroot/libs.and here is my make file. whats is wrong with that.

```
#!bin/sh
CC=gcc
LDLIBS=-lglut -lGLEW -lGL
ROOT=/media/programming/experiments/projectroot

VPATH=../libs:../include
INC=-I$(ROOT)/include

all: triangle
triangle: triangle.o shader_utils.o
         cc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(INC)
shader_utils.o: shader_utils.h
         cc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(INC)    
clean:
        rm -f *.o triangle
.PHONY: all clean
```

when try to make. it tell this

```
cc -c  ../include/shader_utils.h -o shader_utils.o -I/media/programming/experiments/projectroot/include 
cc -c  triangle.o -o triangle -I/media/programming/experiments/projectroot/include
cc: warning: triangle.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule makes no sense:

```
triangle: triangle.o shader_utils.o
         cc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(INC)
```

You are telling Make to construct an executable, but asking it to use `-c`.  Just remove all of your rules and let the defaults work for you.  Rewrite the Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
LDLIBS=-lglut -lGLEW -lGL
ROOT=/media/programming/experiments/projectroot
VPATH=../libs:../include
CFLAGS=-I$(ROOT)/include

all: triangle
triangle: triangle.o shader_utils.o
shader_utils.o: shader_utils.h 
clean:
        rm -f *.o triangle
.PHONY: all clean
```